# Control device (ASUS fan) from Gnome shortcut

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, asus, fan

After some search, the only reliable way I found to control the fan in my ASUS laptop was to issue this commands (as root):

turn on fans:

```
echo 0 > /sys/devices/platform/asus-nb-wmi/hwmon/hwmon7/pwm1_enable
```

turn off (automatic?) fans:

```
echo 2 > /sys/devices/platform/asus-nb-wmi/hwmon/hwmon7/pwm1_enable
```

How can I control these from a Gnome shortcut of another fast method?
I tried making these path read-write from the user (although the privileges are reset on reboot) but then when I put this commands as commands for Gnome keyboard shortcuts they don't execute at all.

**How can I make this run from a shortcut? and additionally (bonus), how can I make it run as root?**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how to get the shortcut to work. We will go along with your original plan and not need root:

1. Paste the following in `/etc/tmpfiles.d/fans-askubuntu-1506330-1004020.conf` . This will change the permissions at every boot to be writable.

   ```
   z /sys/devices/platform/asus-nb-wmi/hwmon/hwmon7/pwm1_enable 666
   ```
2. Wrap your GNOME custom shortcuts in `bash -c` . The default way to launch commands does not support shell-specific syntax, just like how `#!` doesn't support it.

   ```bash
   bash -c "echo 0 > /sys/devices/platform/asus-nb-wmi/hwmon/hwmon7/pwm1_enable"
   bash -c "echo 2 > /sys/devices/platform/asus-nb-wmi/hwmon/hwmon7/pwm1_enable"
   ```